# how to add page wide header to xPage with fixed navbar

Tags: css, xpages, angular-ui-bootstrap, lotus-notes

I have a responsive app. layout with navbar set as fixed-top and pageWidth=fixed

```
    <xe:this.configuration>
        <xe:simpleResponsiveConfiguration fixedNavbar="fixed-top"
            invertedNavbar="false" pageWidth="fixed"...>
```

Now I want to add something like a page header but it should be page width. See picture below. So the blue panel should be page width while its content is fixed. What control can I use for that blue panel/header. Should it be another navbar?

[image]

Comment: the ui-bootstrap side actually implemented this kind of design, you can always check out the source code

Comment: So is there any xPages expert who can show me it in xPage source code?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Bootstrap, I would recommend you create your own custom control that adds a bootstrap row after your navbar. Set the css parameters to fix the position.
The trick here: you can add standard markup into an XPage, so you "just" try what you want to achieve in plain html pages and add the row that worked for you to the custom control.